# Checking for nil string before concatenating

Tags: ruby, code-formatting

This question is similar to a LOT of questions, but in no such way is it anything of a duplicate. This question is about string concatenation and writing better code less than it is for checking nil/zero.

Currently I have:

```
file.puts "cn: " + (var1.nil? ? "UNKNOWN" : var1)
```

Which works fine, but doesn't look good. What is a better way to write this in ruby so that I am checking for nil and not concatenating it

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do this:

```
file.puts "cn: " + (var1 || "UNKNOWN")
```

or, identically if you prefer:

```
file.puts "cn: " + (var1 or "UNKNOWN")
```

**or my favourite, which I think is the most idiomatic ruby:**

```
file.puts "cn: #{var1 or 'unknown'}"
```

Comment: if var1 is `false`, you'll see 'unknown' instead.

Answer (score 21):

Use `join` to add the strings which may be `nil`.

The `join` will not complain if there is a `nil`

For example:

```
["a","b",nil,"c"].join("") 
#=> abc
```

However, if you are joining with anything but a blank string, like an underscore, you will get a join String for the `nil` value:

```
["a","b",nil,"c"].join("_")
#=> a_b__c
```

To fix this, use `.compact` to remove the `nil` values from the `Array` before joining:

```
["a","b",nil,"c"].compact.join("_")
#=> a_b_c
```

Comment: This is true only when joining by an empty ["a","b",nil,"c"].join("_")
=> "a_b__c" (notice the double underscore after 'b')

Comment: @pseudo `["a","b",nil,"c"].compact.join("_")` solves the problem

Comment: @Viktor Thanks. Updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 7):

Using ruby 2.4.1, `to_s` resolves for both `nil` and `"Hello"`.  So `var1.to_s` should suffice.

```
2.4.1 :058 > nil.to_s
 => "" 
2.4.1 :059 > "hello".to_s
 => "hello"
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do what Peter suggested, assuming that `false` wasn't a valid value for `var1`, and `var1` was guaranteed to be `nil` or a string. You could also extract that logic into a function:

```
def display_value(var)
  (var || "UNKNOWN").to_s # or (var.nil? ? "UNKNOWN" : var.to_s) if 'false' is a valid value
end

file.puts "cn: " + display_value(var1)
```

`to_s` is only necessary if `var1` isn't guaranteed to be nil or a string. Alternatively, if you do:

```
file.puts "cn: #{display_value(var1)}"
```

it will do an implicit `to_s` on the result of `display_value`

Answer (score 1):

```
file.puts( "cn:" + (var1 || "UNKNOWN" ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `"cn: "` part is purely aesthetical and therefore (more?) subject to change to meet future presentation guidelines, I would recommend using join;

```
file.puts(["cn", (var1 || "UNKNOWN")].join(": ")
```

Perhaps as a function, as mentioned earlier - semantics are the same, only method names/keywords have changed;

```
def value_or_unknown(value, attribute = nil)
  [attribute, (value or "UNKNOWN")] * ": "
end
```